# Form transparent like background CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing and studying Front-end (HTML/CSS) via FreeCodeCamp. I managed to complete the project but I would like to make my portfolio as presentable as possible.

Googled and searched StackOverflow but couldn't find a specific answer to my issue. I've toyed with the opacity in the body::before, the root rgba and tried to add/remove z-Index in both body and body::before, but my form area still looks transparent where the background should be the only faded image. Any assistance on where I went wrong here?

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
<body translate="no">
  <main id="main">
   <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h1 id="title" class="text-center"> Most Popular Anime of 2020 Survey</h1>
      <p id="description" class="description text"> Please take some time to fill out the following survey. Let's see which anime truly is the top voted for 2020!</p>
    </header>
    <form id="survey-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="name-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="email-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="number-label">Age (optional)</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" id="number" placeholder="Enter your age" min="10" max="100" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p>How long have you watched anime?</p>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="time" value="Less than 1 year" class="input-radio" checked>Less than one year</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="time" value="1-3 years" class="input-radio">1 - 3 years</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="time" value="4+ years" class="input-radio">4+ years</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p> Which anime do you believe deserves to be the top for 2020?</p>
        <select id="dropdown" name="anime" class="form-control" required>
          <option disabled selected value>Please select one of the following anime</option>
          <option value="demon">Demon Slayer</option>
          <option value="dbz">Dragon Ball Super</option>
          <option value="aot">Attack on Titan</option>
          <option value="nob">Noblesse</option>
          <option value="juju"> Jujutsu Kaisen</option>
          <option value="mha"> My Hero Academia</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p>What part of anime do you enjoy best?</p>
        <span class="apply">(Check all that apply)</span>
        <label>
          <input name="list" value="music" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox">Music</label>
        <label>
          <input name="list" value="art" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox">Art</label>
        <label>
          <input name="list" value="story" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox">Story</label>
        <label>
          <input name="list" value="action" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox">Action</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p>Any anime not on the list you would recommend for the next survey?</p>
        <textarea id="comments" name="comment" placeholder="Name a suggestion" class="input-textarea">
      </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

CSS

```
:root{
  --color-white: #f3f3f3;
  --color-darkblue: #1b1b32;
  --color-darkblue-alpha: rgba(27,27,50, 1);
  --color-green: #37af65;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

body{
  font-family: Georgia, Brush Script MT, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: var(--color-white);
  margin: 0;
  z-Index: 1;
  
}
body::before{
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  z-Indez: -1;
  background: var(--color-darkblue);
  background-image:
    url("https://i.postimg.cc/8PMKKM2M/mha.jpg");
  opacity: 0.25;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
h1 {
  font-weight:400;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
p{
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
h1, p{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
label{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
input, button, select, textarea{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
button{
  border: none;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}
@media (min-width: 576px){
  .container{
    max-width:540px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    max-width:720px;
  }
}
.header{
  padding: 0 0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
  color: black;
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.description{
  font-style: italix;
  font-weight 200;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
.apply{
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #e4e4e4;
}
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
form{
  background: var(--color-darkblue-alpha);
  padding: 2.5rem 0.625rem;
  border-radius:0.25rem;
}
@media(min-width:480px){
  form{
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
}
.form-group{
  margin: 0 auto 1.25rem auto;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
.form-control{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.375;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.form-control: focus{
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline:0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}
.input-radio, .input-checkbox{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  min-height: 1.25ren;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
}
.input-textarea{
  min-height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  resize: vertical;
}
.submit-button{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: var(--color-green);
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Result
[image: final result of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css file you wrote `z-Indez: -1;` instead of `z-index: -1;` in `body::before{}` but if you change this your form background color will be your color variable `--color-darkblue-alpha`so the background will not be transparent.

Comment: ..... i just wanna bang my head on the wall lol. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I got it :))
correction:

```
z-index: -1;
```

you coded "z-Indez: -1;" that's why it was not working.
you can see below result:
[image]

Comment: you the man! thank you! can't believe it was one little edit like that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the very slight typo of "z-Indez: -1" to "z-index: -1" should do the trick.

The one thing I'll add is that, sometimes when proof-reading, it's best to read bottom-up because your brain can trick you if only reading top-down.

Hope this reaches you and helps, cheers!